# Codeigniter batch insert query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, insert

I try to insert data in my MySQL table using codeigniter.

First I retrieve the columns from a config XML where I should insert data and the targeted nodes which should give back from another XML the insert values.

```
    foreach ($sql_xml as $children) {
        foreach ($children as $index => $child) {
            if ($child != 'feed_id') {
                $keys[] = $index;
                $into[] = $child; //this holds the table columns
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I retrieve the multiple values per row which I want to insert.

```
  $products = array();
        $data = array();             
        foreach ($target_xml as $feeds) {
            $feeds =  $this->xml2array($feeds); //SimpleXMLObject to array
            $columns = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new  RecursiveArrayIterator($feeds)); //get all recursive iteration            
            foreach ($columns as $index=>$column) {   
                     if (in_array($index, $keys)) { //here I get the values on matching nodes
                        $data[] = $column;
                    }    
                } 
            $products[] = $data;// this are the datas which should be inserted
            }
```

Here should come the insert: I have been looking in docs which has a quite good workaround if the inserted is an associative array which  in my case is created on flow on matching keys.

```
  $this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $products);
```

The problem is that the `into` array which contains the target columns and I don't know how to push theme in my product array.

Comment: Your example code isn't very clear to me, but anyway the 'columnName' should be used as a key & the value is the value of that key so it should look something like this $Products = array( array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Something' ), array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'AnotherProduct'));

Comment: You may use print_r or var_dump to make sure you data looks OK before throwing it at ->insert_batch

Comment: thanks for feedback so the problem is the following the keys are in a separate array $into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand your example code correctly, but here's my try on it.

You want this code

```
if ($child != 'feed_id') {
     $keys[] = $index;
     $into[] = $child; //this holds the table columns
}
```

To be get changed to something like this

```
if ($child != 'feed_id') {
     $keys[$index] = $child;
}
```

And you want this one

```
if (in_array($index, $keys)) {
    $data[] = $column;
}
```

To be change like this

```
if ( array_key_exists($index, $keys) ) {
    $data[$keys[$index]] = $column;
}
```